# Extending a morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field and $X:=V(T_3^2-T_1T_2)\subseteq \mathbb{A}_k^3$. Let $Z:=\{(0,0,0)\}\subseteq X$ viewed as a closed subscheme with reduced scheme structure. Denote by $\widetilde{X}:=Bl_Z X$ the blow-up of $X$ in $Z$.

There is a morphism $g:X\setminus Z\rightarrow \mathbb{P}_k^1$ given by  $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mapsto [x_1:x_3]=[x_3:x_2]$  on k-points

Show: $g$ extends to a morphism $\widetilde{g}:\widetilde{X}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}_k^1$.

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Could someone give me a hint?